# Jump links on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm a beginner in WP theme development, and I'm having an issue with my menu.

My menu contains 4 items, 3 of them leads to differents sections in my frontpage and the last one leads to page that I have created.

I have Added id="section_name" to every section of my frontpage and on Menu section on dashboard of every item,  I referenced to this section by putting the value of id of every section in the link.

Now the issue is when I'm not on the frontpage And I clicked on one of the 3 items of my menu the section doesn't show up , on the frontpage it works fine

Does anyone know how to use jump links in wordpress ?

Thank u all

Answer (score 0):

You could use full URLs.

This is the menu link now:
**#section_name**

And you could try this:

**http://yoursite.com#section_name**

I hope it helps you out.

But this is not really a Wordpress question - you only encountered this case on the Wordpress admin.

Comment: Assuming that the home page is at `/` they could also do `href="/#section_name"`